# determining the end of user char input c++

Tags: c++

i want to proccess user input which is a line of string. with string library it's just easy as `cin >> mystring;` , but for performance reasons, i'd like to process a character at a time without saving previous characters or using any kind of arrays. so i wrote this code:

```
char myc;
while(cin >> myc){
   dosomething(myc);
}
```

but after writing a line of string as input and hitting enter, it processes input characters and still waits for more input characters to come.
i also used `cin.eof()` and `while(myc)` but none of them worked.

Comment: are you looking for `if(myc == '\n') break;`? Or alternatively `while((cin >> myc) && (myc != '\n'))`?

Comment: @user253751 That doesn't work because `std::istream::operator>>` is formatted read and skips newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for line break but you can't do it with `std::istream::operator>>` because it is formatted read and skips newline. Use

```
char myc;
while ((myc = cin.get()) != '\n')
   dosomething(myc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a stream character-wise use [`std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function:

```
for(char c; std::cin.get(c);) {
    std::cout << c;
}
```